# How do we dynamically add alias to complex aggregate?

Tags: django, django-orm

```
for *key*,*value* in dict_test.items():
    data = (Model.objects.filter(id__in=*value*)
                         .annotate(num=Func(F('amount'),
                         template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s AS % (type)s)',
                         function='Cast', type='float')
                       ).aggregate(*key*=Coalesce(Sum('num'),0))
```

Instead of getting **'key'**, I want the actual key from the for loop.

I'm using `Django=1.9.1`

Answer (score 2):

As always, you can use dictionary expansion:

```
).aggregate(**{key: Coalesce(Sum('num'),0)})
```

Comment: I did try this. I am getting the following error `TypeError: aggregate() keywords must be strings
`

Comment: Well what is in `dict_test`? Post the contents.

Comment: This is in dict_test `{3:[1,2,3], 4:[4,5,6], 5:[7,8,9], 6:[0]}`

Comment: Well, those are clearly integers. Why would you want to use an integer as a field name? Please explain what you want the actual output to be.

Comment: Becasue it makes it easier in for the final result.

Comment: As I say, please explain what that final result should be.

Comment: I wanted the result to be for that integer, the total sum. In the end, after the sum of all keys, I will add them to a dictionary which is like {3: 147, 4: 10, 5: 38, 6: 0}